# More nuanced word for know-it-all

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a person who believes themselves to be smarter than others, but  frequently betrays that the opposite is true. For example, when dumb-shaming someone, this person uses their big words incorrectly, but confidently. Know-it all isn't quite right, because there's a chance a know-it-all  might actually know quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**egotist** noun. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/egotist)

> A conceited, boastful person.

An egotist is a self-absorbed, bragging person. From Latin: ego = I.

As in:

> Toby, vigilant about his diet and insecure about his height, is
>   persuasive as a well-meaning egotist. The New YorkerJun 27, 2019

Comment: This word is not about professing knowledge, which 'know-it-all' is.